# Char to unsigned char

Tags: c, char

I have a buffer structure with a field

```
    char inc_factor;
```

which is the amount of bytes to increment in a character array. The problem is that it must be able to hold a value up to 255. Obviously the easiest solution is to change it to unsigned char, but I'm not able to change the supplied structure definition. The function:

```
    Buffer * b_create(short init_capacity, char inc_factor, char o_mode)
```

Takes in those parameters and return a pointer to a buffer. I was wondering how I would be able to fit the number 255 in a signed char.

Comment: Are you writing the `b_create` function?

Comment: Yes I'm writing the b_create function. The structure was given, but it must be able to take up to 255 as a parameter

Comment: I don't get it, if the calling code was given, why are they trying to pass a value btw 0 to 255 value??, i mean they expects a char, not an unsigned char, but they are passing a value which doesn't fit in a char...

Comment: "char" tends to indicate an 8-bit value. a "signed char" (short: "char") uses the highest bit to denote sign, an unsigned doesn't. Both of them can still only store values 0x00-0xff. The signed vs unsiged prefix simply determines interpretation.

Comment: Beats me. Specifications just say that it has to x.x . Ill ask if it was supposed to be unsigned. Maybe it was a typo because I think this is impossible otherwise

Comment: @JosipDorvak i think is simply wrong hehe, it doesn't make sense, i mean, you can store 255 diferent values, but btw -128 to 127, maybe you can map the values according that so, -128 = 0, and so on

Comment: @DGomez "negative" numbers in modern computers are already basically mapping. "0x80" (128) is -127 and "0xff" (255) is -1. So all you have to do is cast it to an unsigned value to remove the interpretation of the sign value. (one reason it's done this way is that if you add 1 to (byte)0xff you get '(byte)0x00 + [carry flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag)')

Comment: Plain `char` *may or may not* be able to hold values from 0 to 255. Plain `char` has the same range and representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`; it's implementation-defined which one it is. They're still three distinct types. (More obscurely, it's possible to have `CHAR_BIT > 8`, in which case even `signed char` can represent values from  to 255 -- but you're not likely to encounter such an implementation.)

Comment: For another theoretically allowed architecture which you're unlikely to see in the wild, it's possible that a signed char can only represent values from -127 to +127, inclusive; the 256th value could be a trap representation, or a negative 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the type:

```
unsigned char n = inc_factor;
```

Signed-to-unsigned conversion is well defined and does what you want, since all three char types are required to have the same width.

You may need to be careful on the *calling* end (or when you store the `char` in your structure) and do something like `f(n - UCHAR_MAX)` or so (since again, if this is negative and `char` is unsigned, all is well).

Comment: still need to store the inc_factor inside the struct. buff->inc_factor = n . Would still cause an overflow. Also I'm not creating the calling code...just the implementations of all the functions

Comment: @JosipDorvak : Assigning inc_factor *will not* cause an overflow, merely a reinterpretation - the bit pattern remains teh same and can be passed between signed or unsigned char variables interchangeably.  As Kerrek has pointed out, you have to be careful in arithmetic expressions since that involves an implicit cast to int (a larger type).

Answer (score 1):

Lets use the term "byte" to represents 8-bits of storage in memory.

A byte with the value of "0xff" can be accessed either as an unsigned character or as a signed character.

```
BYTE byte = 0xff;
unsigned char* uc = (unsigned char*)&byte;
signed char* sc = (signed char*)&byte; // same as "char", the "signed" is a default.
printf("uc = %u, sc = %d\n", *uc, *sc);
```

(I chose to use pointers because I want to demonstrate that the underlying value stored in memory is the same).

Will output

```
uc = 255, sc = -1
```

"signed" numbers use the same storage space (number of bits) as unsigned, but they use the upper-most bit as a flag to tell the cpu whether to treat them as negative or not.

The bit pattern that represents "255" (11111111) unsigned is the same bit pattern that represents -1. The bit pattern "10000000" is either 128 or -127.

So you can store the number "255" in a signed char, by storing "-1" and then casting it to an unsigned int.

EDIT:

In-case you're wondering: negative numbers start "at the top" (i.e. 0xff/255) for computational convenience. Remember that the underlying storage is a byte, so if you take "0xff" and add 1, just using normal, unsigned cpu math, it produces the value "0x00". Which is the correct value for "i + 1" when "i = -1". Of course, it would be equally odd if negative numbers started with "-1" having the value 0x80/128.

Comment: Oops, I thought the question was tagged c++, replaced stream operators with good ol' printf :)

Comment: lol :) I know about all that. Just the value HAS to be positive. I could always cast it every time I use it :/

Comment: There are a lot of times when legacy code has an API that just uses "char" because they didn't care so much (compilers were less rigorous), especially with network data, etc. So just cast it. Personally, I would rename the variable in the function implementation to "inc_factor_" and as the first line of the function declare `unsigned char inc_factor = (unsigned char)inc_factor_; // there'll be no decrementing for you!`.

Comment: @JosipDorvak : You only need to cast within b_create, if you pass an unsigned char to b_create, the compiler will implicitly cast it to char (which may be signed or unsigned - it is compiler dependent)

Answer (score 0):

You COULD cast it.

```
 (unsigned char)inc_factor = 250;
```

And then you could read it back also with a cast :

```
 if( (unsigned char)inc_factor == 250 ) {...}
```

However, that's really not best practices, It'll confuse anyone who has to maintain the code.

In addition, it's not going to help you if you're passing inc_factor into a function that expects a signed char.

There's no way to read that value as a signed char and get a value above 128.

Comment: I guess I could do this temperarely. It's for an assignment so maintainability isn't really a huge importance. I'll get clarity on the issue on another day.

Comment: `(unsigned char)inc_factor` is not an lvalue in C.

Comment: You have to cast the RHS of the assignment, not the LHS: `inc_factor = (char)250;`. But the cast specifies a conversion that's done implicitly, so it's not necessary. Casting to `unsigned char` before a comparison is necessary, though.